# Oracle SQL - select column of explicitly defined values

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I had a table like:

mytable

```
Name  |  Age  
Jack     20
Joe      33
John     4
Bob      0
```

Suppose that I want to select all rows from mytable along with a custom column of values: `random : 'rabbit','wild', 'nuts'` yielding:

```
Name  |  Age  |  random
Jack     20      rabbit
Joe      33      wild 
John     4       nuts
Bob      0       NULL
```

How might one go about this?

Comment: Where do you get the values from?

Comment: preferably manual keying as part of the query statement

Comment: What do you mean "manual keying"? Do you have a table of those values, a function? Do you want to pick up a random value for each row?

Comment: `Row_number()` both sets and `left join` by numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit more flexible, but also more complex…

```
WITH random AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (1)) rank, val FROM (
    SELECT 'rabbit' AS val FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'wild' AS val FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'nuts' AS val FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS val FROM DUAL
  )
  ORDER BY dbms_random.value
),
myrows AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (1)) rank, mytable.*
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT myrows.Name, myrows.Age, random.val
FROM myrows
LEFT JOIN random ON myrows.rank = random.rank;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f785d/1

Answer (score 1):

You can add column with random string using [dbms_random](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm)

```
 CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,4)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'rabbit' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'wild' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'nuts' 
        WHEN 4 THEN null
   END AS random
```

[Similar answer][2[

Answer (score 0):

You want `case` expression ?

```
select t.*, (case when age = 20 then 'rabbit' 
                  when age = 33 then 'wild' 
                  when age = 4 then 'nuts' 
             end) as random
from table t;
```

Comment: no there are no conditions at all, I'd just like to be able to pass a list of values as another column as part of the `select`, is such a thing possible?